# Discover possible combinations in permutation triads with specific criteria

Tags: python, dataframe, set, permutation

This is the [spreadsheet](https://ufile.io/uhb97) I'm working on. As you can see, the spreadsheet is in a really messy state. I have done some cleaning of the data as per the description below:

- Each column heading denotes the Period/lesson in the day
- each day has 7 periods/lessons- therefore monday to friday = 35 columns
- each cell contains the class descriptor( the first 3 characters), the intitals of the teacher (3 characters after the "$" sign) and the room name ( which is the 3 characters after the "(" ).

I want to get teachers into groups of 3 (triads) where the following criteria is true:

- At any given period/lesson in the week 2 teachers are "free" not teaching and 1 teacher is teaching.
- within that very same triad in a different period there is a different teacher who is "not free" and Teaching, where the other 2 teachers are teaching
- in addition in any other period the other combination of 2 teachers being "free" non teaching and the unused teacher is teaching.

See following idea for further clarification:

Initials A AND B are in the set but not  C present in set
     ALSO  C AND A in the set but not B present in set
     ALSO  B AND C in the set but not A present in the set
     All 3 criteria must be true to work find the final triad

so there should be out of the thousands permutations not many combinations that fit that criteria

In simple terms, what I'm trying to find is to place teachers into groups of 3. Where 2 teachers can go into and observe the lesson of another teacher, ie, in any period, 2 teachers are free and one is teaching. You will see in each column all the teachers who are teaching at any given period and day. Therefore anyone who is not in that column we can deduce is not teaching.
We want the group of 3 teachers to remain as a triad so the each get to be observed. So in any other period in the week a different teacher is teaching from the same triad and the other 2 are NOT teaching.

This is the code I've written so far to clean up the data and create the possible triads. I do not know if this is the best approach to the aforementioned problem, but in any case, this is what I've done so far. I am currently stuck in how I can find the intersections between all these triads in order to correctly identify the teachers who fulfill the above criteria.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools

class unique_element:
    def __init__(self,value,occurrences):
        self.value = value
        self.occurrences = occurrences


def perm_unique(elements):
    eset=set(elements)
    listunique = [unique_element(i,elements.count(i)) for i in eset]
    u=len(elements)
    return perm_unique_helper(listunique,[0]*u,u-1)


def perm_unique_helper(listunique,result_list,d):
    if d < 0:
        yield tuple(result_list)
    else:
        for i in listunique:
            if i.occurrences > 0:
                result_list[d]=i.value
                i.occurrences-=1
                for g in  perm_unique_helper(listunique,result_list,d-1):
                    yield g
                i.occurrences+=1


def findsubsets(S, m):
    return set(itertools.combinations(S, m))


csv_file = pd.read_csv('Whole_School_TT.csv')
df = csv_file.dropna(how='all')
df = csv_file.fillna(0)
cols = df.columns
df_class_name = df.copy()
df_names = df.copy()
df_room_number = df.copy()

for col in range(0, len(df.columns)):
    for row in range(0, len(df)):
        if df[cols[col]].iloc[row] is not 0:
            text = df[cols[col]].iloc[row]
            index_dollar = df[cols[col]].iloc[row].find('$')
            r_index_dollar = df[cols[col]].iloc[row].rfind('$')
            if index_dollar is not -1:
                if index_dollar == r_index_dollar:
                    df_names[cols[col]].iloc[row] = df[cols[col]].iloc[row][index_dollar+1:index_dollar+4]
                else:
                    name1 = df[cols[col]].iloc[row][index_dollar + 1:index_dollar + 4]
                    name2 = df[cols[col]].iloc[row][r_index_dollar + 1:r_index_dollar + 4]
                    df_names[cols[col]].iloc[row] = name1 + ' ' + name2
                index_hash = df[cols[col]].iloc[row].find('#')
                df_class_name[cols[col]].iloc[row] = df[cols[col]].iloc[row][:(index_dollar - 1)]
                df_room_number[cols[col]].iloc[row] = df[cols[col]].iloc[row][index_hash + 1:-1]
            else:
                df_names[cols[col]].iloc[row] = 0
                index_hash = df[cols[col]].iloc[row].find('#')
                if index_hash is -1:
                    df_class_name[cols[col]].iloc[row] = df[cols[col]].iloc[row][:3]
                    df_room_number[cols[col]].iloc[row] = 0
                else:
                    df_class_name[cols[col]].iloc[row] = df[cols[col]].iloc[row][:(index_hash - 2 )]
                    df_room_number[cols[col]].iloc[row] = df[cols[col]].iloc[row][index_hash + 1:-1]

teacher_names = []
for col in range(0, len(cols)):
    period_names = (df_names[cols[col]].unique())
    teacher_names.extend(period_names)

df_all_names = pd.DataFrame(teacher_names, columns=['Names'])
df_all_names = pd.DataFrame(df_all_names['Names'].unique())
df_all_names = df_all_names[(df_all_names.T != 0).any()]
mask = (df_all_names[0].str.len() == 3)
df_single_names = df_all_names.loc[mask] # so now here we have all the teacher names in general who teach
# we will find the teacher who teach per period and teachers who do not teach
set_of_names = set(np.array(df_single_names[0]))  # here i have all the unique teacher names

period_set_names = [0]*len(cols)
period_set_names_NO_teach = [0]*len(cols)

# here i get the names for each one of the periods
# and find the intersection with the unique teacher names in order to figure out who teaches per period
for col in range(0, len(cols)):
    period_set_names[col] = set(np.array(df_names[cols[col]]))  # get teacher names for current period
    period_set_names_NO_teach[col] = set_of_names.difference(period_set_names[col])
    period_set_names[col] = set_of_names.intersection(period_set_names[col])
    # sanity check
    print('Teachers who teach and teacher who dont teach should be equivalent to the full list of names: ', end='')
    print(period_set_names_NO_teach[col].union(period_set_names[col]) == set_of_names)

def get_current_period_triplets(col):
    free_period_pairs = findsubsets(period_set_names_NO_teach[col], 2)  # I got all the period Free teacher pairs
    # teaching_period_pairs = findsubsets(period_set_names[col], 2)
    free_period_pairs_list = list(free_period_pairs)
    period_triplets = []
    for i in range(0, len(free_period_pairs_list)):
        listof = list(free_period_pairs_list)
        current_free_pair = list(listof[i])
        # print(current_free_pair)
        for j in (period_set_names[col]):
            temp = current_free_pair.copy()
            current_triplet = temp.append(j)
            period_triplets.append(tuple(temp))
    period_triplets = set(period_triplets)

    return period_triplets


for col in range(0, len(cols)):
    current_triplets = get_current_period_triplets(col)
    print(current_triplets)
```

Comment: Tour link/image does not work.
Please, provide what have you tried by now, with a sample of input and a sample of intended output.

Comment: I edited the post. Please kindly check it again. I have provided the input.